# Java - Hibernate : Generate sequence column based on another field

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Need to add a field to the database which will record a sequence number related to that (foreign) id.

```
Example table data (current):

ID     ACCOUNT     some_other_stuff
1      1           ...
2      1           ...
3      1           ...
4      2           ...
5      2           ...
6      1           ...
```

I need to add a sequenceid column which increments separately for each account, achieving:

```
ID     ACCOUNT     SEQ     some_other_stuff
1      1           1       ...
2      1           2       ...
3      1           3       ...
4      2           1       ...
5      2           2       ...
6      1           4       ...
```

Note that the sequence is related to account.

Comment: There is no direct way of doing this. I recommend you to create a trigger with the logic while inserting a record in database and set the value of seq column.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be done with JPA and hibernate. The only solution would be to do it manually in the service. You can use @Generated value on a column but that relies on the database to provide the value. And you cannot create a custom sequence implementation and use @GeneratedValue because that works only for the ID column.