# Hibernate: How to generate sequence for a field in embedded id

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have an @EmbeddedId based on 4 columns. 3 which are an UUID FK and 1 that should be sequential.

```java
@Embeddable
public class MyId {

  @JoinColumn(name = "column_1_id", referencedColumnName = "column_1_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "column_2_id", referencedColumnName = "column_2_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "column_3_id", referencedColumnName = "column_3_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false)
  private Relationship relationship;

  @Column(name = "sequential_id", columnDefinition = "sequential_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer sequential;
}
```

The problem is that the sequential column should be auto generated based on every column_2_id, something like:

| column_1_id | column_2_id | column_3_id | sequential_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | 1 |
| A | A | A | 2 |
| A | A | B | 3 |
| A | A | B | 4 |
|  |  |  |  |
| B | **B** | C | **1** |
| B | **B** | C | **2** |
|  |  |  |  |
| B | C | D | 1 |
| B | C | D | 2 |

Any ideia how this could be achieved with Hibernate?

I'm fine with directions, I would be really, really grateful with any comments if you don't feel like writing the full answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Same problem as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529690/java-hibernate-generate-sequence-column-based-on-another-field

Comment: JoinColumns don't work in embeddable Ids, so I assume you are trying to set this up  in JPA using reference mappings and are hopefully using derived ID and 'mapsId' on the relationship mappings to let JPA set these values for you. Assuming that, what operation do you have or that is going to know how to determine your 'sequential_id' value - this seems error prone, as what happens when you remove one row (say with a 1 value) and try to insert a new one? You are better off using a sequential ID as your ID and avoid the complexity and overhead in trying to map this

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your answer. Precisely, the example with the join columns was just to illustrate, thank you for interpret correctly, I'll fix the example to make it more consistent. That being said, removal is not a problem and I need this ID at runtime, ideally, I need it to be returned to be used in the same transaction and should be a unique sequence per ```column_2_id```.

Comment: It seems a calculated data point though, not a true sequence. And removal isn't a problem - it is a question. When row with value 1 is removed, what is the 'next' value that gets assigned? Efficiently tracking sequences for each of these combinations will be cost prohibitive and why I suggest just using a single sequence and ID value for your rows/entities. I don't see the need for a composite PK of this nature, and it will complicate linking to this entity in future references. Have it use its own UUID or DB assigned sequence for a unique ID independent of this natural, compound id

Comment: Otherwise, on the how - you can use a pre persist event to assign your own value to this property. Calculating the current one will be a pain. Hibernate allows specifying generators on composite ID properties when using an ID class, so you can also define your own sequence generator ( https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/ ) but I don't know how you would really write it to query the DB to figure out the 'next' value for your use case.

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris. I'll consider this and I'll be discussing with the rest of the team. Currently I'm thinking on doing some big changes to the whole solution as it will be less of a pain really.